# how to read from an array without a particular column in python

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7, pandas, data-analysis

I have a numpy array of dtype = object (which are actually lists of various data types). So it makes a 2D array because I have an array of lists (?). I want to copy every row & only certain columns of this array to another array. I stored data in this array from a csv file. This csv file contains several fields(columns) and large amount of rows. Here's the code chunk I used to store data into the array.

```
data = np.zeros((401125,), dtype = object)
for i, row in enumerate(csv_file_object):
    data[i] = row
```

data can be basically depicted as follows

```
column1  column2  column3  column4  column5 ....
1         none     2       'gona'    5.3
2         34       2       'gina'    5.5
3         none     2       'gana'    5.1
4         43       2       'gena'    5.0
5         none     2       'guna'    5.7
.....     ....   .....      .....    ....
.....     ....   .....      .....    ....
.....     ....   .....      .....    ....
```

There're unwanted fields in the middle that I want to remove. Suppose I don't want column3.
How do I remove only that column from my array? Or copy only relevant columns to another array?

Comment: Are you looking to process the CSV input before it gets into the `numpy` array, or to remove columns from the array after it's been created? (Or just "whichever is easier" or "whichever is faster"?)

Comment: @maheshakyha: Then I think root's answer is the easiest. If you can't/don't want to replace your reading with `pandas.read_csv`, then probably my `numpy.delete` is easiest, but I think you're better off with his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). Also it seems to me, that for various type of data as yours, the `pandas.DataFrame` may be  better fit.

```
from StringIO import StringIO
from pandas import *
import numpy as np

data = """column1  column2  column3  column4  column5
1         none     2       'gona'    5.3
2         34       2       'gina'    5.5
3         none     2       'gana'    5.1
4         43       2       'gena'    5.0
5         none     2       'guna'    5.7"""

data = StringIO(data)
print read_csv(data, delim_whitespace=True).drop('column3',axis =1)
```

*out:*

```
   column1 column2 column4  column5
0        1    none  'gona'      5.3
1        2      34  'gina'      5.5
2        3    none  'gana'      5.1
3        4      43  'gena'      5.0
4        5    none  'guna'      5.7
```

If you need an array instead of DataFrame, use the `to_records()` method:

```
df.to_records(index = False)
#output:
rec.array([(1L, 'none', "'gona'", 5.3),
           (2L, '34', "'gina'", 5.5),
           (3L, 'none', "'gana'", 5.1),
           (4L, '43', "'gena'", 5.0),
           (5L, 'none', "'guna'", 5.7)], 
            dtype=[('column1', '<i8'), ('column2', '|O4'),
                   ('column4', '|O4'), ('column5', '<f8')])
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the OP's question—you've still got column 3 there!

Comment: Yeah, if the OP is willing to change his reading code, and he wants to use `pandas`, this is probably the best way. (Except you're still not deleting column 3, you're deleting column 2… But I doubt anyone will have any problem figuring that out.)

Comment: @abarnert -- I think finally got the cols right, thanks again :)

Comment: I just noticed that he already had `pandas` as a tag on his question, so… yeah, this is definitely the way to go. `read_csv` is much simpler, harder to get wrong, and probably faster than what he has, and there's no good reason not to drop the column in `pandas` instead of post-deleting after `to_records`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're reading the CSV rows and sticking them into a `numpy` array, the easiest and best solution is almost definitely preprocessing the data before it gets to the array, as Maciek D.'s answer shows. (If you want to do something more complicated than "remove column 3" you might want something like `[value for i, value in enumerate(row) if i not in (1, 3, 5)]`, but the idea is still the same.)

However, if you've already imported the array and you want to filter it after the fact, you probably want [`take`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html#numpy.take) or [`delete`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html):

```
>>> d=np.array([[1,None,2,'gona',5.3],[2,34,2,'gina',5.5],[3,None,2,'gana',5.1],[4,43,2,'gena',5.0],[5,None,2,'guna',5.7]])
>>> np.delete(d, 2, 1)
array([[1, None, gona, 5.3],
       [2, 34, gina, 5.5],
       [3, None, gana, 5.1],
       [4, 43, gena, 5.0],
       [5, None, guna, 5.7]], dtype=object)
>>> np.take(d, [0, 1, 3, 4], 1)
array([[1, None, gona, 5.3],
       [2, 34, gina, 5.5],
       [3, None, gana, 5.1],
       [4, 43, gena, 5.0],
       [5, None, guna, 5.7]], dtype=object)
```

For the simple case of "remove column 3", `delete` makes more sense; for a more complicated case, `take` probably makes more sense.

If you haven't yet worked out how to import the data in the first place, you could either use the built-in [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module and something like Maciek D.'s code and process as you go, or use something like [`pandas.read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) and post-process the result, as root's answer shows.

But it might be better to use a native `numpy` data format in the first place instead of CSV.

Answer (score 1):

You can use range selection. Eg. to remove column3, you can use:

```
data = np.zeros((401125,), dtype = object)
for i, row in enumerate(csv_file_object):
    data[i] = row[:2] + row[3:]
```

This will work, assuming that csv_file_object yields lists. If it is e.g. a simple `file` object created with `csv_file_object = open("file.cvs")`, add `split` in your loop:

```
data = np.zeros((401125,), dtype = object)
for i, row in enumerate(csv_file_object):
    row = row.split()
    data[i] = row[:2] + row[3:]
```

Comment: +1. Except that I wouldn't recommend `split` for parsing a CSV file—that's what the stdlib `csv` module is for.